# Is this question spam?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, spam

I stumbled upon this question on the main site:

> If you were to choose between the name ‘Merkato.com’ and ‘Fynshop.com’ to brand the next ‘Buy & Sell’ website here in Asia which name would you pick? If choices above don’t suit your taste and you feel you have a better name in your mind, let me know about it.

The blatant opinionatedness and off-topicness aside, does it qualify for the spam flag? It looks like an advertisement for an eBay-like site, but both domain names mentioned in the question are for sale.

Btw, the question was tagged with [branding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branding) instead of random tags that are completely irrelevant.

Comment: It's just opinion based, not spam really. Is it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  "...but both merkato.com and fynshop.com are for sale" -- this makes it really really slippery ([astroturfing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astroturfing)?) I am not sure if straight spam flag would work but I would consider custom mod flag for that

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQLbwOGT8eM

Comment: Wait a second, the question was tagged properly and it didn't have a nonsensical wording... this is starting to look less like spam.

Comment: Oh dear, you seem to have stumbled across a veritable [gold mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branding) of poor-quality and off-topic questions.

Comment: Do know that the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room handles a lot of SPAM reports so if you need a quick check on a post feel free to drop in.

Comment: I don't see and sausage, pork _or_ ham anywhere in that post. Just a question that has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There will always be a gray area between 'spam' and 'not spam'. It is certainly possible to see this as spam for a domain registration service, but not everybody will agree. Trust me, questions like these are sometimes asked with honest intentions. Therefore, I personally wouldn't flag it as spam.

That said, it's clear that this is not content which belongs to Stack Overflow. I can't find the question, but I expect it to be down-, close- and delete-voted fast.